# Could not find ChessboardCorners in following picture

Tags: c++, opencv

I have tried following code to find corners of square boxes in attached chess board picture but unfortunately could not find it. Can you please inform me what can i do to detect corners of chessboard in this case...Many thanks ..:)

```
int main() {
cv::Mat imgOriginal;        // input image
Size  boardSizeTopChessBoard;
boardSizeTopChessBoard.width = 144;  
boardSizeTopChessBoard.height = 3;
vector<Point2f> pointBufTopChessBoard;
bool topChessBoardCornersFound = false;

imgOriginal = cv::imread("topChessBoard.jpg");         
imshow("Original Image ", imgOriginal);

topChessBoardCornersFound = findChessboardCornersSB(imgOriginal, boardSizeTopChessBoard, pointBufTopChessBoard, 0);


if (topChessBoardCornersFound)
{
    cout << "Corners found in top chess baord" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Corners not found in top chess baord" << endl;
}
waitKey(0);
return(0);
```

}[image: Test Picture]

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of reasons why it doesn't work.

First of all, image appears to have small resolution with this amount of corners. Therefore, it is too dificult to detect them.

Secondly, the constrast at the edges of image is lower which makes it more difficult. Darker image is harder to detect.

And finally, try to capture sharper image. This one is little bit blurry.

Comment: thank you very much for your help.. I will try the solution provided by you and will update you ..